# Stata's -margins- shows negative predicting value for count model

Tags: poisson-distribution, stata, prediction, fixed-effects-model

I am modeling "Innovation" counts over "HHI" and "squared HHI" with fixed effect poisson model. (My sample is unbalanced, small & wide one.) I am aware of that I can use Stata's -margins- command to obtain the estimated innovation count based on observable values. Below are my codes and results:

```
    xtpoisson innovation hhi c.hhi#c.hhi fee age c.age#c.age size c.size#c.size, fe
    margins, dydx(*)
    margins, at(hhi=0.0001(0.005)0.100)
```

The estimated coefficient for HHI is 32.80 and for squared HHI is -131.31. The "Average Marginal Effect" of HHi is 25.37. However, when I used the third line to get the "marginal effect at representative values," all predicted values are negative. I am surprised because I thought I was modeling some positive count number and I don't understand why I got negative predicted values, e.g.,-3.xx innovations, which is generated from the sample mean of all dependent variables.

My questions may be three-fold:
1) Do I understand -margins- results correctly? Or I missed something?
2) Is there any coding mistakes that may result to what I got now?
3) If there is no coding mistakes, does the result imply that my fixed effect poisson model have some problems?

A bit more information: when I plot the observed innovation over HHI fit with quadratic line, the curve is u-shape and above zero. However, when I use the -marginscontplot- command to plot the predicted innovation over HHI, it's an inverted u-shape and below zero.

Thank you for your help!